# How to store images for flutter in a database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to store pictures for a group chat in flutter and Firestore. I tried using Firebase storage but I'd have to create a separate storage place for each group. Maybe you have a way to store it somewhere. I also need to show it on the homepage of the user.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to create separate storage for each group.

Comment: then how do I display the image in the group chat?

Comment: Magic. Same as you store all groups data in Firestore. You literally can have there terabytes of images, and you can sort them, kinda like in Firestore.

Comment: What i achive this before is upload images to Storage then get the downloadURL, Then save downloadURL to firestore.

Comment: Well I did using base64 strings in the document then you convert that base64 String to a file and that is, it all worked!

Comment: @Loading,Let me know if the below recommendations were helpful.

Comment: I just edited the way it would be saved in the database by adding the group name

Answer (score 0):

The chat page allows you to send images. The sent images can be uploaded/stored on the Firebase storage.Also after hosting these images the paths from the device's local storage can be fetched using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and then finally display these images.

Also check the following examples for similar implementations:

- [Which Database should be used for flutter app using images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753532/which-database-should-i-use-for-my-flutter-app-using-lots-of-images)
- [Upload and store image using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348279/upload-and-store-image-into-firebase-using-flutter)
- [How to send images in flutter chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862498/how-to-send-images-in-chat)
- [How to share image file from flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175980/how-to-share-image-file-from-flutter-app-to-other-apps)
- [How to display image in app with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161862/how-to-send-an-image-to-an-api-in-dart-flutter)